# How to throw an exception if an event is not triggered by Jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a modal window, which triggers a `shown` event when it is loaded.

I want to throw an exception (or perform some action) if the event is not triggered in given time period (e.g. 1s).

Any suggestions on how to implement it using jQuery?

Comment: You want to throw an exception when what is not triggered in a given time, The modal being shown, or some user action on the modal?

Comment: Can interpret this several different ways. Please be more specific about higher level problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I will try to explain it with more clarity. @LamarOliphant: I want to throw an exception if "shown" event is not triggered on the modal within a specific time period.

Comment: Please edit your post and include your JQuery code and what you have tried in regards to this issue so far.